# Javascript code runs only when debugging

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, twitch

I am on using Twitch api to check if selected channels are online or offline. Having a weird bug. Code works only when debugging the script in dev tools. Am I missing anything?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var channels = ["OgamingSC2","sheevergaming", "ESL_SC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
        for (var i = 0; i < channels.length; i++) {
            $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + channels[i] + '?callback=?', function(data) {
                if (data.stream) {
                    $('.wrapper li').eq(i).css('background-color', "blue");
                } else {
                    $('.wrapper li').eq(i).css('background-color', "red");
                }

            });
        };

    })
```

Here is the full code http://codepen.io/nikasv/pen/GqRMXq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.getJSON()` is asynchronous.  As such, it's completion callback is called some time later.  Your `for` loop runs to the end and then when the callback is called, `i` is set to the end of the `for` loop.

Debugging may changing the timing of things.

You can fix things by embedding the loop counter in an IIFE so it will be uniquely captured for each iteration of the `for` loop like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var channels = ["OgamingSC2","sheevergaming", "ESL_SC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
      for (var i = 0; i < channels.length; i++) {
          (function(index) {
            $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + channels[index] + '?callback=?', function(data) {
                if (data.stream) {
                    $('.wrapper li').eq(index).css('background-color', "blue");
                } else {
                    $('.wrapper li').eq(index).css('background-color', "red");
                }
            });
          })(i);
      }
 });
```

Or, you can use `.forEach()` which makes the inner function for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var channels = ["OgamingSC2","sheevergaming", "ESL_SC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
      channels.forEach(function(item, index) {
            $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + item + '?callback=?', function(data) {
                if (data.stream) {
                    $('.wrapper li').eq(index).css('background-color', "blue");
                } else {
                    $('.wrapper li').eq(index).css('background-color', "red");
                }
            });
       });
 });
```

Comment: A less awkward solution would be to just use `channels.forEach(function(index) { ... });`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - Good idea.  I added that option to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to include jquery in your code

If you open console it say $ is not defined. Add jquery and it will work fine.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add jquery at page ( Settings - javascript - quick-add - jquery - close )

After - all works fine ( _http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xOxXQN )

[image]